# Social Plugins: URL redirects in Like plugin and Comments plugin

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I have integrated Like button and Comments plugin in my website. Recently some of the URLs for which comments and likes created are changed.

I am sending proper redirects (301) from old urls to new urls, how long will it take Facebook to detect the url and update likes & comments?

Will Comments & Likes from my old url be transferred to my new url?

**UPDATE: Its been 2 days since the urls changed. I didnt see the Likes and Comments migrate to the new URL.**

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I move a URL via 301 redirect and retain the page's Facebook likes and Open Graph information?](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7197919/how-can-i-move-a-url-via-301-redirect-and-retain-the-pages-facebook-likes-and-o)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this bug report:
http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=18198

Comment: As you can see, its been a quite some time since the urls changed. The Bug Report says i should put the old url in the href tag for the likes to show up. I cant do it now, since the new urls have likes which will be lost. I am surprised FB is not handling a simple use case like this.